# EditText background base line color changing based on its focus in android

Tags: android, colors, background, android-edittext

I need to design EditText with base line showed in below image and it will be change to some other color when it receives focus.!

[image]

i am using the following.

```
 <EditText    
    android:id="@+id/mobilenumber" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mobile"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="@string/mobilenumber"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

    />
```

So, please guide me how to handle this.

Comment: read about StateListDrawable tag <selector> in xml

Comment: Can you some clear idea about this ?

Answer (score 71):

You can add theme for EditText

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

And you can use in EditText as

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
   .......................
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">

</EditText>
```

Comment: If you want to control the color of the tip when it goes up above the field when the field is selected, add the same theme to the TextInputLayout which is wrapping your EditText.

Comment: This will crash on oppo devices. Removing the colorControl params in style fixes it. Trying to find a better solution

Comment: How can I set Theme for EditText dynamically ?

Answer (score 19):

use this in your editText style

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/focus_tint_list</item>
```

focus_tint_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>

   <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#999999"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: where do you put the file focus_tint_list.xml?

Comment: In res create `color` resources directory, then create `focus_tint_list` color resource inside color directory

Comment: How can I set Theme created dynamically to EditText ? What can I do to set that theme dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

Try Holo Color generator for custom colors.

[Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

You can create Selector and set it as background of the `EditText`

**res/drawable/edit_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />

</selector>
```

**layout :**

```
<EditText    
    android:id="@+id/mobilenumber"
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text" />
```

Comment: Nice answer. Your XML Code misses </selector> tag though. Other than that - thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing, and I solved it in the following way:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true">
   <shape>
     <stroke android:color="@color/blue_500" android:width="2dp" />
     <corners android:radius="45dp"/>
   </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_window_focused="false">
  <shape>
    <stroke android:color="@color/grey_600" android:width="2dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="45dp"/>
  </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks best answer

Comment: Where do we need to set this selector file for the baseline of EditText?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the baseline of EditText when it is on focus you can simply go to the colors.xml file in your project and change the "colorAccent" value.

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
<color name="colorAccent">#DESIRED_COLOR</color>
</resources>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programeticly as these steps:

1- Create a **color** directory to the **res** directory
2- Create XML selector file has colors focus states like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#535353"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</selector>
```

3- Use this code:

```
val colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.focus_tint_list)
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(editText, colorStateList)
```