# Is there anyway to change the GREEN color of this TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, xml

I want to change the green color of this label only with XML code. Is there any way?

[TextInputEditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnXRe.png)

Comment: Post your code pls

Comment: try this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219296/how-to-change-color-of-text-input-underline-and-text-when-clicked) cheers buddy Linus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout/57811487#57811487

Answer (score 0):

Use this 3 line of code in your TextInputEditText xml file.

```
            app:boxStrokeColor="#008000"
            app:hintTextColor="#008000"
            android:textColorHint="#008000"
```