# Android EditText Tint Color Change during click or active

Tags: android

I have the Four EditText field. I have changed the backgroundTintcolour and cursor colour of the edit text. But I want to change the colour of the backgroundTintcolour during active of the edit text only. If I leave the edit text from one to another it should change it to default black colour. How to do this?

Comment: try it using styles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449169/how-to-change-style-of-a-default-edittext

Comment: get help from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417443/change-border-color-when-edittext-is-focused & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661788/edittext-background-base-line-color-changing-based-on-its-focus-in-android