# change EditText background baseline color when focused in new version of android studio 4.1.x

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, background-color

in older version of android studio when you focused on desired EditText, you could change the baseline and hint color by changing the `@color/ColorAccent` in colors.xml. But in new version of Android Studio v4.1.1 colorAccent is missing from colors.xml. and those elements get color of  `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>`  in themes.xml as image below:

[image]

I think in new material design colors of action bar and edittext must be the same. Now i want to change the focused EditText color without changing actionbar color.
this is my code :

in activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username_TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"
    app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/CharacterOverflow"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_TextField"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

on themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MateialDesign" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Navigation bar color-->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/purple_500</item>
    
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/popup_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="CharacterOverflow">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorError</item>
</style>

<style name="CounterStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAcc</item>
</style>
```

I test all solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661788/edittext-background-base-line-color-changing-based-on-its-focus-in-android) and also i can not set a drawable image for baseline because i wanna change color of overflowed text when counter reach to max. after test many solutions i confuse what should i do! i define `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>` in themes.xml but that doesn't work too.